# How can I finish the mission High Noon?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I have problems killing Pulaski in the mission High Noon. I am stuck in the desert and he flees. The only car I get is a Bandito (Buggy).

I tried to shoot and crush my Bandito into his car, but somehow either he escapes or my Buggy gets destroyed.

I even tried to bring a good car, but somehow I cannot find it once the mission starts.

How can I finish this mission?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you use the method in the following video:

> As soon as the mission starts, shoot the wheels of the car Pulaski is about to enter

The mission shouldn't prove to be a problem while Pulaski escapes driving around in circles...

Answer (score 5):

Here are some tips from [strategywiki.org](http://strategywiki.org/wiki/Grand_Theft_Auto:_San_Andreas/High_Noon)

### Tips

- A Sanchez is usually spawned by the Verdant Meadows save. With that, or any bike, drive up to the red marker and park the bike by the building closest to the road. After walking to the red marker and going through the cut-scene, the bike will still be there.
- Before you start the initial cutscene, have a powerful gun armed, like the AK47 or M4. As Pulaski runs toward the car, he can't be hurt. You can shoot out the tires, so that he can't get any speed. Drive along him and shoot him up as he mocks your family. When he starts to burn he'll bail out. Get a small distance away and shoot him up with the AK47/M4 to put him down fast.
- It is also possible to chase him down with the chainsaw before he gets in the buffalo.
- If you have either stolen a Hunter from the Air races, or gotten all gold medals in your Learning to Fly training missions, the Hunter makes this mission relatively easy. If you don't have access to the Hunter, get yourself a Seasparrow before this mission. Fly your copter to the ghost town, and land it by the road, to the south of the town. Make sure you are a good distance away from the graveyard. Then, once he gets in the Buffalo, you can run to your copter, chase him down and blow up the car from the air. You will still have to kill Pulaski himself.
- It is possible to block Pulaski with your buggy as he gets inside the car then carjack him. You can then run him over and kill him. The same cutscene is shown, but in that method, you don't hear him mocking your family. This method is very difficult and may require several tries.

Follow these tips and i'm sure you wont have any problems.

Answer (score -1):

I have two tips if you are using cheat then type all car blast code cpktnwt a cut scene appear and carl ask him for your wish and then kill him but if do not use cheat then just chase him I have do this mission with  both methods. I have completed san andreas 3 times first time intake two or three months second time in 3 days 3 time in 2 days
so if you any problem just ask me but make

sure only pc users